# what is the meaning of '-' in file name?

Tags: security, filenames, passwd

In the /etc, I found several commands with '-':

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  916 Jul  1  2015 group-
----------. 1 root root  733 Jul  1  2015 gshadow-
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2261 Apr 25  2015 passwd-
----------. 1 root root 1252 Apr 25  2015 shadow-
```

of course, there are also their original ones.

Since 'group' and 'passwd' are important, could anyone explain the meaning and the possible reason? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are usually system-generated backup files. Feel free to ignore them.

Comment: _system-generated backup files_ is not specific IMHO. Consider expanding a bit.